# python mechanize form submitting error

Tags: python, mechanize

```
import mechanize

br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
formno=-1

br.open(raw_input("enter the url"))
allforms=br.forms()

for form in allforms:
    print "form name:",form.name

    print "lets get to work"

for form in br.forms():
    formno=formno+1
    print "*"*20
    print "working on form ",form.name
    #form.set_all_readonly(False)
    print formno
    br.select_form(nr=formno)
    print "boss"
    for control in br.form.controls:
        if control.readonly is True:
            pass
        else:
            print control.name
            form[control.name]='sparsh'

    resp=br.submit()
    resp=resp.get_data()
    print resp
```

Output:

```
enter the url http://www.howtogeek.com/
form name: None
form name: None
form name: None
lets get to work
********************
working on form None
0
boss
emailaddress
emailaddress False
email
email False

One more step!
Make sure to check your email for a confirmation message.

Note: If you do not get it soon, check your Spam or Junk folders.

hello
********************
working on form None
1

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\thesis\data\form_mechanize_try.py", line 21, in
br.select_form(nr=formno)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 524, in select_form
raise FormNotFoundError("no form matching "+description)
FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 1**
```

Why am i getting this error?

What i am trying to achieve is to fill all the forms available in a particular website and see the response.. but the above code is just able to select the first form and after that giving error

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an unnamed form. Here is  the correct syntax :

```
# List the forms that are in the page

for form in br.forms():
    print "Form name:", form.name
    print form

# To go on the mechanize browser object must have a form selected
br.select_form(nd = "form1")         # works when form has a name
br.form = list(br.forms())[0]  # use when form is unnamed
```

Python for beginners has a great cheat sheet about mechanize : http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet/